# jQuery UI button with smoothness theme grows when clicked and held

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-ui, button

I would like to display a jQuery UI selectmenu with a list of games and also display 2 buttons to iterate through the list of games and have prepared a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/367dfev0/9/) for that:

[image: jsFiddle screenshot]

**HTML code:**

```
<form>
  <select name="games" id="games"></select>
  <button id="prevGame">&lt;</button>
  <span id="currGame">Game #2</span>
  <button id="nextGame">&gt;</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
$("#games").selectmenu();

setTimeout(function() {
  updateGamesMenu();
}, 6000);

$('#prevGame').button().click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#currGame').html('<i>Prev game</i>');
});

$('#nextGame').button().click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#currGame').html('<i>Next game</i>');
});

function updateGamesMenu() {
  var yourGames = [];
  for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    yourGames.push('<option value="' + i + '">Game #' + i + '</option>');
  }
  var yourGroup = '<optgroup label="Your turn">' + yourGames.join('') + '</optgroup>';

  var hisGames = [];
  for (i = 5; i < 9; i++) {
    hisGames.push('<option value="' + i + '">Game #' + i + '</option>');
  }
  var hisGroup = '<optgroup label="Their turn">' + hisGames.join('') + '</optgroup>';

  $("#games").selectmenu('destroy')
    .append(yourGroup)
    .append(hisGroup)
    .selectmenu();
}
```

It works fine (except for the minor issue of the selectmenu not being vertically aligned with the 2 buttons).

But when I put the same code into [my Wordpress website](http://slova.de), the buttons turn orange and **the buttons increase their size when clicked and held (aka onmousedown)**.

Why does it happen please?

I've inspected the button elements in Firefox console and have noticed that the buttons get `ui-state-active` CSS style, when I click and hold, but I am not sure where to look further.

[image: Wordpress screenshot]

**UPDATE:**

I've copied the buttons-related section from [Wordpress twentythirteen theme style.css](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css) into [my updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/367dfev0/10/) and now can reproduce the issue there:

```
/* Buttons */
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"] {
    background: #e05d22; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e05d22 0%, #d94412 100%); /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */
    background:   linear-gradient(to bottom, #e05d22 0%, #d94412 100%); /* W3C */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b93207;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 11px 24px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

button:hover,
button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus {
    background: #ed6a31; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ed6a31 0%, #e55627 100%); /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */
    background:   linear-gradient(to bottom, #ed6a31 0%, #e55627 100%); /* W3C */
    outline: none;
}

button:active,
input[type="submit"]:active,
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="reset"]:active {
    background: #d94412; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d94412 0%, #e05d22 100%); /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+ */
    background:   linear-gradient(to bottom, #d94412 0%, #e05d22 100%); /* W3C */
    border: none;
    border-top: 3px solid #b93207;
    padding: 10px 24px 11px;
}
```

So this makes my question CSS-related - why do the buttons grow in size when clicked?

As a CSS-rookie I have tried commenting the last 2 lines, but that does not help:

```
/* border-top: 3px solid #b93207; */
/* padding: 10px 24px 11px; */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
button:active
```

from

```
button:active, input[type="submit"]:active, input[type="button"]:active, input[type="reset"]:active {
    background: #d94412;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d94412 0%, #e05d22 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d94412 0%, #e05d22 100%);
    border: none;
    border-top: 3px solid #b93207;
    padding: 10px 24px 11px;
}
```

Or just set it's padding to 0.

```
button:active{
    padding: 0;
}
```

This will prevent it from expanding on being active (click).

One way to see the element states is by inspecting in chrome and using inspector tools:

[image]

Or use the fact that those buttons have their ID's so

```
button#nextGame:active,
button#prevGame:active{
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding (since Wordpress way is to add own style) `button:active, input[type="button"]:active { padding: 0; }` does not seem to help: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/367dfev0/18/). Also I think the `padding` is used there to make the button move down by 1px when clicked. So I still wonder, why the button grows.

Comment: Then just add more specificity. In your case the button has id so you can target that id `button#prevGame` and `button#nextGame`.